# Refer to the month and year in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to pass a script that is in mysql to PostgreSQL, but there is a sentence this in mysql that generates me problems:

```
$q1="select * from noticias where month(fecha)='".$elmes."' and year(fecha)='".$elanio."'";
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: no existe la funcion
>   month(date) LINE 1: select * from noticias where month(fecha)='03' and
>   year(fech... ^ HINT: Ninguna funcion coincide en el nombre y tipos de
>   argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversion explicita de
>   tipos. in C:\xampp\htdocs\calendario\index.php on line 131

How do you see the month and year with PostgreSQL?

Comment: Can you share the table structure and error message in English? thanks

Comment: You should be able to use date_part: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: $q1="select * from noticias where date_part(month)(fecha)='".$elmes."' and date_part(year)(fecha)='".$elanio."'"; ???????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q1="select * from noticias where date_part('month', fecha)=".$elmes." and date_part('year', fecha)=".$elanio;
```

Note that the month and year parameters are not quoted.